# Ignore files that were previously added and deleted

Tags: svn

After accidentally adding a temporary folder, I deleted it with `svn delete path/to/tmp` and committed.

Then I added it to my ignore file and ignored it with:

```
echo path/to/tmp >> .svnignore
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .
```

The problem is that when the `tmp` folder reappears, SVN is still seeing it. So `svn status .` gives me:

```
?       path/to/tmp
```

Printing `svn propget svn:ignore` shows the line I added is there, and I don't have the same issue with other ignored folders.

EDIT: I can reproduce the problem with nested folders. Just not folders in the root.

It's annoying more than anything. I'm unsure if the earlier add/delete mistake is related - as per edit. It seems to be only nested folders.

Can anyone advise how I can clean this up?

---

`svn, version 1.10.4 (r1850624) on x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0`

Comment: Did you commit change of `svn:ignore`? Does `svn status` show anything else?

Comment: how do I commit that? I thought it was a local setting? Status shows nothing else.

Comment: just updated my Q to reflect that dir is nested. I think this might be relevant.

Comment: Fixed. I didn't realise I had to go into `path/to` and ignore `tmp` in there.

Comment: :) I couldn't reproduce your issue - now understand why not :)